# Hooking Common Dialog

Tags: c#

Can anyone help me How to hook OS Common Dialog?

Comment: yes...Coz i need to detect the Save button click of OS Common Dialog

Answer (score 1):

[CommonDialog.HookProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.commondialog.hookproc.aspx) There is an example.